# What are the advantages of the 'mField' Android code style if any?

Tags: android, coding-style

I've been following Google code style for Android without further thinking for a while. Now I'm thinking are there any real advantages of naming fields like `mXXX` as Google does? Seems a bit like Hungarian notation in C++ that is the '`m`' seems a bit redundant? But then why wise people in Google are using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mXxx stands for member variable, sXxx is a static member variable and XXX_XXX is a static final member variable. this is documented [here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions)

Comment: But if I'm using Eclipse what are the advantages if following those guidelines? To put it the other way: are all of those advantages outside Eclipse?

Comment: It really has nothing to do with what IDE you are/aren't using. It is primarily a code readability technique. It is useful for quickly identifying what type of variable you are working with. Another useful scenario is mutator methods. `setSpeed(int speed) { this.speed = speed }` can look confusing to some, but `setSpeed(int speed) { mSpeed = speed }` looks a bit better.

Comment: the advantage has nothing to do with eclipse. this naming convention is made, so you always know with what kind of variable you are dealing. if you follow this convention you can never confuse a local variable with a member variable for example. you also know which ones are static and which ones are final, just by their names.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard, the `m` prefix indicates that it's what one might call a "member variable", ie an attribute contained in the class. By prefixing with `m`, one could easily distinguish when they're dealing with the members of a class and not a local variable.

However, it's more important to write understandable code, in other words with readable filenames that state their cause. `mFoobarvar` isn't too helpful, while `textView` is "better". :)

Comment: Right, but then Eclipse highlights those and Google recommends Eclipse.  Hah, nah you should rethink 'textView' it's a bit like 'understandableName_502'

Comment: Well, if you only have one TextView in the class, it's quite functional. But yes, it wasn't the greatest example ever ha. :)